# Azure Sandboxes and local PowerShell: Unable to acquire token for tenant

Tags: powershell, azure

I am currently working through the excellent Azure learning modules provided under docs.microsoft.com.

Many of the learning modules require a sandbox. Each sandbox creates a new Directory called `Microsoft Learn Sandbox`, that contains a `Resource group` with namings like `learn-0403b111-21e7-4a92-a2f4-cd55e33a1e2d`.

So far so good. Now I would like to access this sandbox via my local `Azure PowerShell` installation and therefor followed allong the offical [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-azure-subscriptions-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

However when issuing a `Get-AzSubscription` it returns with a warning and wont let me use this temporary subscription.

[image]

Why is that? I am not sure anymore, but I though this was possible in the past. Did Microsoft change some access rules? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Asking the obvious, but I assume you have run login-azAccount?

Comment: Thx for replying. Yes I did login. Otherwise I wouldn't see the "Free Trial" subscription.

Comment: If you've logged in previously but  your token is expired you can still see the subscription list, but not do anything else